# Nginx + PhpFpm + phpmyadmin upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) and recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) errors

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I am having connection timed out and connection reset by peer error 503 on Nginx + Phpfpm 7.1 setup.

```
2018/06/28 14:32:13 [error] 2428#2428: *45 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.10.1, server: , request: "GET /phpmyadmin/db_structure.php?server=1&db=britam HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock", host: "192.168.10.192"
2018/06/28 14:39:01 [error] 2428#2428: *51 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.10.1, server: , request: "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock:", host: "192.168.10.192"
2018/06/28 14:41:01 [error] 2428#2428: *56 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.10.1, server: , request: "GET /phpmyadmin/db_structure.php?server=1&db=britam&ajax_request=true&ajax_page_request=true&_nocache=1530196749597737784&token=yYGJ2q%2FE_%2BD6v!Wg HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock:", host: "192.168.10.192"
```

I know I have already Googled my heart out and applied all sorts of suggestions such as setting request_terminate_timeout=30s or more in /etc/php/7.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf and setting max_execution_time = 30 in /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini and finally fastcgi_read_timeout 300; in servers section in nginx configs, then and restarting both Nginx and Phpfpm services.  None of all these options has worked.

Here's my Nginx config;

```
server {
    listen   80 default_server;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/phpmyadmin_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/phpmyadmin_error.log;

    # Main application:
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # phpMyAdmin:
    location /phpmyadmin {
        root /usr/share;
        index index.php;
    }
    # PHP files for phpMyAdmin:
    location ~ ^/phpmyadmin(.+\.php)$ {
        root /usr/share;
        index index.php;
        #fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    }

    # PHP files for the main application:
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Max execution time of 30? Are you sure? That's REALLY low for larger SQL inserts or anything for that matter if the connection to the SQL database is slow or if the uplink is congested. 600 would be a good start for that value as some SQL functions can take extremely long.

Comment: lt doesn't matter what size I increase that figure. Still the same thing.

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind is that your MySQL/MariaDB may be closing connections due to its own interactive_timeout and/or max_allowed_packet size. You should take a look at those as well - it's possible that your SQL server has a very low interactive timeout and it's dying due to that.